# Imaginary part $\frac{R+\jmath \omega L}{1+\jmath \omega LR-\omega^2CL}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fractions

Someone can help me with stupid algebraic steps. 
I can't find the imaginary part of the following expression.

$$Z=\frac{R+\jmath \omega L}{1+\jmath \omega LR-\omega^2CL}$$
$$\jmath=\sqrt{-1}$$
R,L,$\omega$,C are real constants.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Remember most people here, or at least many, come from mathematics. What is $\;\omega\;$ ? Perhaps $\; \omega=e^{2\pi i/3}\;$ ? Explain your notation. Are $\;C,\,L,\,R\;$ constants?

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: hint: multiply numerator and denominator by the complex conjugated denominator

Comment: ω is the angular frequency, and  physicists $j$ is indeed he mathematicians $i$.

Comment: @Bernard phsyicsts don't use $j$ only silly electrical engineers ;-)

Comment: @tired And for a very good reason :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$Z=\frac{R+wLi}{1-w^2CL+wLRi}\cdot\frac{1-w^2CL-wLRi}{1-w^2CL-wLRi}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac{\left(R-w^2RCL+w^2L^2R\right)+\left(wL-w^3CL^2-wLR^2\right)i}{\left|1-w^2CL+wLRi\right|^2}$$

So the imaginary part is

$$\frac{wL-w^3CL^2-wLR^2}{\left|1-w^2CL+wLRi\right|^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator. This way the denominator is turned into a strictly real number:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Z&=\frac{R+\jmath\omega L}{1-\omega^2CL+\jmath\omega LR}\times\frac{1-\omega^2CL-\jmath\omega LR}{1-\omega^2CL-\jmath\omega LR}\\
&=\frac{R-\omega^2CLR+\omega^2L^2R+\jmath(\omega L-\omega^3CL^2-\omega LR^2)}{(1-\omega^2CL)^2+(\omega LR)^2},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
so that the imaginary part of the expression is equal to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\omega L-\omega^3CL^2-\omega LR^2}{(1-\omega^2CL)^2+(\omega LR)^2}.
\end{equation}